# Prevent the removal of paragraphs when submitting a form

Tags: html, express

I am using Node.js and Express to create a blog post.

When I submit the form, any paragraphs I have used in the text area are removed. How can I fix this?

Code below:

```
 <div class="form-group">
          <label for="description">Description</label>
          <textarea class="form-control" type="text" name="description" id="description" 
          placeholder="Blog Post"></textarea>
 </div>
```

Comment: \n in a textarea is meaningless to output in an html element.

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are submitting plain text. You must submit HTML along with the form to be stored in the DB.

You should be using something like TinyMCE to automatically parse the text otherwise you have to manually make the html tags when you write the post! :)